# Need help modeling a train system with SimPy

Tags: python, model, simulation, traffic-simulation, simpy

I need help modeling a train system (like a subway system) in SimPy, the problem is that my "Simulation" teacher wants me to use Python + SimPy and I don't have a clue how to use it, after a week reading about SimPy I managed to understand the bank example, it's easy, but now I still don't have an idea on how to model the problem the teacher gave me...

The problem is large and extensive, but I just need a little help, not the whole project done, so, if some one can help I will realy appreciate.

The reduced problem that will help me get started is like this:

imagine you have 3 stations (A, B, C) separated by some distance (lets say 100m) and I have 2 trains, one on A and one on C (train1 going from A to C, tran2 going from C to A) where each train has a maximum speed (lets say 50m/s for both) and acceleration (lets say 5m/s^2 and -5m/s^2 for breaking) and all they have to do is to stop on each station for a few seconds (lets say 24s) and continue to the next station, when they reach the end, they wait for and extra 20seconds (changing rails) and then start all over again.

The station has a limit of passengers (they dont need to be simulated) the only thing is that each station has a random number of passengers and when the train arrives some get up and others get down...

so, basically I need a small model of the train and the stations with those 3 stations... If some one can help me please...

The real problem has 22 stations, 2 extra stations to change lanes, random time on wait, 42 trains with different max speed and capacity, different number of passengers generated depending on the station and time of day, etc... all this stuff I can manage later, but the modeling logic of the train-station system I can't seem to figure it out... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am by no means an expert with SimPy, but this should get you started:

```
"""
Simulation of a train network
"""
from SimPy.Simulation import *
from math import sqrt
from random import randint
from itertools import cycle

def timeTo(A, maxV, d):
    """
    Given a trapezoidal velocity envelope defined by
    A       constant acceleration, m/s/s
    maxV    maximumum velocity, m/s
    return time in seconds required to travel
    d       distance, m
    """
    tA = float(maxV)/A          # time to accelerate to maxV
    dA = A*tA*tA                # distance traveled during acceleration from 0 to maxV and back to 0
    if (d < dA):                # train never reaches full speed?
        return sqrt(4.0*d/A)        # time needed to accelerate to half-way point then decelerate to destination
    else:
        return 2*tA + (d-dA)/maxV   # time to accelerate to maxV plus travel at maxV plus decelerate to destination

class Train(Process):
    def __init__(self, name, sim, accel=1.0, maxV=50.0, passengers=0, maxPassengers=400):
        super(Train, self).__init__(name, sim)
        self.accel = accel
        self.maxV  = maxV
        self.p     = passengers
        self.maxP  = maxPassengers

    def roll(self, route):
        here = route.next()     # starting location
        for dest in route:
            # travel to next station
            print "{:.1f}s: {} leaving {} for {}".format(self.sim.now(), self.name, here, dest)
            yield hold, self, timeTo(self.accel, self.maxV, here.distanceTo[dest])
            # arrive at next station
            here = dest
            print "{:.1f}s: {} at {}".format(self.sim.now(), self.name, here)
            yield hold, self, here.arrive(self)

    def getOff(self, num):
        if self.p >= num:
            print "  {} passengers got off".format(num)
            self.p -= num
        else:
            num = self.p
            print "  train is empty - only {} passengers got off".format(num)
            self.p = 0

    def getOn(self, num):
        if (self.maxP is None) or (self.p + num <= self.maxP):
            print "  {} passengers got on".format(num)
            self.p += num
        else:
            num = self.maxp - self.p
            print "  train is full - only {} passengers got on".format(num)
            self.p = self.maxp

class TrackNode(object):
    def __init__(self, name, delay=5.0):
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay
        self.distanceTo = {}
    def arrive(self, train):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Station(TrackNode):
    def arrive(self, train):
        train.getOff(randint(1,15))
        train.getOn(randint(1,15))
        return self.delay

class Switch(TrackNode):
    def arrive(self, train):
        print("  switching tracks")
        return self.delay

class SampleRailroad(Simulation):
    def run(self, maxTime=100.0):
        self.initialize()
        # create places
        x = Switch("switch x", 20.0)
        A = Station("Station A", 24.0)
        B = Station("Station B", 27.0)
        C = Station("Station C", 25.0)
        y = Switch("switch y", 18.0)
        # distances between places
        x.distanceTo[A] = 50.0
        A.distanceTo[B] = 5000.0
        B.distanceTo[C] = 2000.0
        C.distanceTo[y] = 80.0
        y.distanceTo[C] = 80.0
        C.distanceTo[B] = 2000.0
        B.distanceTo[A] = 5000.0
        A.distanceTo[x] = 50.0
        # set up first train
        sf = Train("Santa Fe 219", self)
        self.activate(sf, sf.roll(cycle([A,B,C,y,C,B,A,x])), at=0.0)
        # set up second train
        cn = Train("Canadian National 41", self, maxPassengers=200)
        self.activate(cn, cn.roll(cycle([C,B,A,x,A,B,C,y])), at=5.0)
        # start simulating!
        self.simulate(until=maxTime)

def main():
    rr = SampleRailroad()
    rr.run(800.0)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I created a framework for simplying these types of simulations with simpy. See: https://github.com/dov/onedmotion/blob/master/xz-motion.py .